# Compilar con la version de android: (plaforma de destino) - Android 8.1

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin

Estoy tratando de probar un proyecto de GitHub con **Xamarin**, pero al hacerlo me pide que se compile con la version de **Android 8.1**. El problema es que al intentar cambiar la plataforma de destino no me aparece el 8.1, solo el 8.0 y me sigue dando el error.

Ya instale el SDK 8.1 y 9 con sus imagenes, no hay actualizaciones pendientes, ya intente limpiar y recompilar el proyecto, y aun nada.

Alguien tiene idea de como puedo agregar el Android 8.1 a las versiones disponibles para compilar?

[image: Imagen de error]

[image: Imagen No me aparece 8.1]

[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: Tienes que agregar el android 8.1 y luego procederá a descargarlo a tu maquina local

Comment: Actualiza Visual Studio a su última version, e intentalo de nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intente de todo pero no pude solucionar el error en el SDK Manager.

Lo solucione utilizando las máquinas virtuales de **Genymotion** (Oracle VM), fue muy fácil de usar.